# How can I make a command to open second window and close the main window in python(class)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

**How can I make a command to open second window and close the main window in python.**

The code can open the next window but it cant close the main window..

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = first(root)


class first:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("First")
        tit = Label(self.master, text="Im the first page", font=20)
        tit.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        sec = Button(self.master, text="Second", width=20, height=10,
                     bg="black", fg="white", command=self.second_open)
        sec.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    def second_open(self):
        self.secondwindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = second(self.secondwindow)


class second:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Second")
        tit = Label(self.master, text="Im the second page", font=20)
        tit.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not just reuse the first window? What's the point in destroying it and recreating it?

Comment: have you tried the code that I put?

Comment: Yes, I ran your code. I still don't know why you think you need to destroy and recreate the main window. This code isn't doing anything that seems to require new windows.

Comment: I don't mean to reopen the main window,
I mean opening the second window at the same time closing the main window.

Comment: I hope that you have understand me!

Comment: No, I don't understand. If you're closing one and opening another, why not just re-use the original window? You can remove all of the widgets and add new widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter is designed for you to create one root window, and keep that window until the program ends. That makes it difficult to do what you ask.

A better solution in many cases is to just keep and reconfigure the main window instead of destroying it and creating a new window.

Here's an example based on the code in the question:

```
def second_open(self):
    for child in self.master.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    self.secondwindow = second(self.master)
```